# Sanity check on definitions from arrays

Tags: c, definition

I'm hunting for the cause of a bug and think I may have found it if my understanding of using `#define` is correct.

As i understand it, once you define something, its set that way, even if the define is filled with the value of a variable, it sticks with the value at the time of compile and would not change if the variable changed later? So this code:

```
int values[] = {5,6,7,8};
int x = 0;
#define DEF_VALUE values[x]
```

DEF_VALUE would be 5, as 5 is the value of position 0 in the values array.

But if I was to do this:

```
int values[] = {5,6,7,8};
int x = 0;
#define DEF_VALUE values[x]
x = 2;
```

DEF_VALUE would still be 5 as that was the output of values[x] at the time that #define was called, so changing the value of x later to 2 would not cause a change in DEF_VALUE to 7 (the value of position 2 in the values array).

Is my logic here correct?

If so I think I've found my bug as the original programmer of this code was relying on updating x to update the value of DEF_VALUE later in the code for a location address for selections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way `#define` works in C is that it creates an *expansion*, that is any place where `DEF_VALUE` occurs, the compiler treats it as if `values[x]` was written. The C pre-processor effectively re-writes the code by applying these expansions and the resulting re-written code is what's supplied to the compiler.

In this case changing `x` has the effect of changing what `DEF_VALUE` ultimately *evaluates* to, but not what it expands to.

In your second case it expands to `7` if and only if `x` is `2`. If this `#define` is used in another scope then the results are unknown or a syntax error depending on what variables are present.

Some test code:

```
void demo() {
  int values[] = {5,6,7,8};
  int x = 0;
  #define DEF_VALUE values[x]
  x = 2;

  printf("%d\n", DEF_VALUE);
}
```

Here it shows `7` as expected.

Once the pre-processor has finished with this code it ends up in this form:

```
void demo() {
  int values[] = {5,6,7,8};
  int x = 0;
  x = 2;

  printf("%d\n", values[x]);
}
```

If later in your code you have this:

```
void other() {
  printf("%d\n", DEF_VALUE);
}
```

You get a syntax error. That's because the code the compiler is told to work with is actually:

```
void other() {
  printf("%d\n", values[x]);
}
```

As neither `values` nor `x` are present in that scope it can't compile.

Comment: Ah great, thank you for the explanation. Shame that that means I haven't found the source of the bug, but glad to have had my understanding of #define corrected.

Comment: @solexious: An attempt at finding a bug -- any bug, really -- usually requires *reproducibility*. Complete source example, observed output, expected output. Actually, any question on StackOverflow asking "why doesn't this work as expected?" that does not come with a [mcve] is usually attacting close-votes pretty fast. ;-)